# Where did Magneto get his helmet from?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, magneto

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Apocalypse (En Sabah Nur) gives Magneto his helmet. In *X-Men: First Class*, Magneto gets his helmet from Sebastian Shaw.

Are these two movies in the different universe or does Magneto have two helmets?

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking where the helmet came from, as in your title (and self-answered)? Or whether the two movies are in the same universe (as in the text)?  Or perhaps are you trying to find out what happened to the old helmet and why he needed a new one? You might want to reconcile the title and text and intended question.

Answer (score 51):

## Same timeline, different helmets.

The events of *First Class* and *Apocalypse* are in the same timeline / universe.   There is no contradiction here.  After the events of *Days of Future Past*, Magneto gives up his mutant life and the Magneto persona to raise a family in Poland and work an honest job.  We don't know exactly what happened to his first helmet in the intervening time.  After

> the death of his new family,

he accepts the invitation to join Apocalypse's cause.  Apocalypse demonstrates an exceptional control over matter, and we see him fabricating intricate suits for his Four Horsemen with ease using only his mutant powers.  **Apocalypse fashions Magneto's new helmet in a similar way, literally out of dust.**

Anecdotally, I have two identical copies of the same baseball cap and, as far as I know, all the moments of my life have occurred within a single cinematic universe.

Comment: That means the helmet we generally see is the one he got from Apocalypse.  The one which he got from Shaw was used till he started his honest life.  So in Days of Future Past, in Future Magneto have this new helmet.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal : Not necessarily.  The future events in *Days* are in a timeline that is disjoint from the events of *Apocalypse* (although *First Class* is in the past of both).  We don't know how many helmet changes Magneto had in the timeline leading up to the future part of *Days* or where he got them from.

Comment: “It is likely that Apocalypse fashioned Magneto's new helmet in a similar way.” — I’m fairly sure we see the helmet being fabricated (from, like, dust) by Apocalypse in the movie.

Comment: What is the name of your cinematic universe?

Answer (score 17):

We actually see at least five different helmet designs within the [x-men-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe), including at least two physically different helmets.

Chronologically, the first one he has is the one he takes from Shaw in *X-Men: First Class*. Shaw received the helmet from the Russians.

[image: stop. magnet time.]

At the end of the movie, he has repainted it, and added some flair. (Note: I am not counting this in my five-count)

[image: my helmet is now all pretty and fancy]

Eleven years later, during the past events of *Days of Future Past*, Magneto's helmet looks different. Whether or not this is the same helmet, modified again, is unclear.

[image: don't you know who i am?]

During the events of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Apocalypse provides Magneto with a new helmet, seemingly "made" of sand. This appears to be a physically new helmet. The helmet is again, a dramatically different design.

Exactly what happened to his helmet between *Days of Future Past* and *Apocalypse* is unclear, but Erik has attempted to abandon his old life and ways. Discarding or even destroying his old helmet doesn't seem out of the question.

[image: apocalypse said we could go for ice cream]

Some 20 years later, Magneto is seen with a very different helmet design. We see Toad painting it from a dull grey to purple, but it's unclear if this was a new helmet (from the *DoFP* era, since *Apocalypse* never occurred in this timeline) or a modified one.

[image: does this helmet make my face look fat?]

In *The Last Stand*, he has a different design again. It's similar to the one from *X-Men*, with more contours and more hard edges.

[image: i'm getting too old for this]

Comment: Magneto looks so grumpy in that *Apocalypse* image. "Fine, I'll eat my vegetables, but don't expect me to enjoy them."

Comment: I recall Shaw's helmet being introduced with "The Russians made this".  (Some bitrot may have occurred during storage in my meat-brain.)  That's microscopically more detail than "Its exact origin is unknown."

Comment: I love this answer :) . These superb images made it even more beautiful. Thanks man.

Comment: I was going to post a similar question, but this answers where Shaw got it from initially... though why the Russians would develop an anti-telepathy helmet is another question altogether. Shame the movies couldn't start with the red & purple one and keep that design, 'cuz it's perfect.